# Visible Property of ASP.Net Control not working

Tags: asp.net

I have a radiobutton list and  three placeholders in my page, out of which the radiobutton list,first and third placeholder are within updatepanel, second placeholder is not within updatepanel.

When radiobutton list selectionindex is changed, I want all three placeholders invisible. Placeholder2.visible=false code executes but still Placeholder2 is visible.

How to resolve this.

Thanks,
Viknesh.A

Comment: PostBack inside UpdatePanel will cause any server side changes to be applied only on the controls inside that UpdatePanel. This is by design behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You should put all your placeholders in update panel on reload the page when the radio button hits (full post back) by setting `AutoPostBack="true"`

You should understand that by default changin radio button on a client only affects client html, so you need to pass that info to server.

Another option is to have client onclick for radiobutton and write your custom javascript function to hide your second placeholder, but don't forget to manage that situation on the server as well, when postback (either ajax or not) will occur.

Comment: I cant have all my placeholders in update panel as one of my Placeholder(Placeholder2) is having file upload control, which I don't want to be placed in update panel.

Comment: so go with my second suggestion wrap toggle display css property for the second placeholder on client side and make sure it will be handled on the server side when postback occurs.

Comment: My Javascript:                                              function Plchold_invisible() 
{
  document.getElementById('Placeholder2').style.display = 'none';
}

Comment: yep, but if the name is autogenerated, it's better use something like document.getElementById('<%=Placeholder2.ClientId%>')

Comment: but Javascript function is not firing when it is invoked.

Comment: hey you should fire it on event and add onclientclick for the radiobutton and manage some logic as well, not to use as it is.

Comment: hey I am using VS2008 I couldn't find onclientclick for radiobutton list, but I resolved it by adding onClientClick for my submit button. Now its working fine. Thanks Alexsuslin. your post was really useful. For radiobutton list I am not able to find onClientClick property in VS2008.

Comment: I guess for radio button it will work just onclick and can be added e.g. thru code behind like Radio1.Attributes.Add("onClick", ....)

Answer (score 1):

Move Placeholder2 inside the UpdatePanel.

Or don't use an UpdatePanel at all.

Or use JavaScript to hide it, instead of server-side code.